# Why does filling my viewport height makes flexbox work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am learning the ropes with bootstrap 4 and I stumbled across a little problem with flexbox. I was trying to align a text in the center of the page and it only worked when I added the class to fill the viewport. Why does it only work when I am using it? I can't wrap my head around it and I thought you guys could give me a hand. It's a tiny piece of code so I'll post everything I wrote.

```css
.fill-viewport {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section id="introduction">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row fill-viewport align-items-center">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Some text here</h1>
            <p>Please center </p>
            <a href="#" role="button">Try it yesterday</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: Evidently, the CSS class is in a separate stylesheet. I just pasted the code below the HTML so you guys can see everything I included in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by the default the height of the row is the height of the content it contains. Therefore `align-items: center` has no effects visually.

Once you declared `height` or `min-height`, then `align-items` starts making effects.

Examples:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<div style="height:100px;">Hello</div>
```